# accessing a variable from another class

Tags: java, variables

Very simple question but I can't do it. I have 3 classes:

**`DrawCircle` class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DrawCircle extends JPanel
{
    private int w, h, di, diBig, diSmall, maxRad, xSq, ySq, xPoint, yPoint;
    public DrawFrame d;

    public DrawCircle()
    {
        w = 400;
        h = 400;
        diBig = 300;
        diSmall = 10;
        maxRad = (diBig/2) - diSmall;
        xSq = 50;
        ySq = 50;
        xPoint = 200;
        yPoint = 200;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawOval(xSq, ySq, diBig, diBig);

        for(int y=ySq; y<ySq+diBig; y=y+diSmall*2)
        {
            for(int x=xSq; x<w-xSq; x=x+diSmall)
            {
                if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(yPoint-y,2) + Math.pow(xPoint-x, 2))<= maxRad)
                    {
                        g.drawOval(x, y, diSmall, diSmall);
                    }               
            }
        }

        for(int y=ySq+10; y<ySq+diBig; y=y+diSmall*2)
        {
            for(int x=xSq+5; x<w-xSq; x=x+diSmall)
            {
                if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(yPoint-y,2) + Math.pow(xPoint-x, 2))<= maxRad)
                {
                    g.drawOval(x, y, diSmall, diSmall);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`DrawFrame` class**

```
public class DrawFrame extends JFrame
{
    public DrawFrame()
    {
        int width = 400;
        int height = 400;

        setTitle("Frame");
        setSize(width, height);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new DrawCircle());
    }
}
```

**`CircMain` class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CircMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

One class creates a frame, the other draws a circle and fills it with smaller circles. In `DrawFrame` I set width and height. In `DrawCircle` I need to access the width and height of `DrawFrame`. How do I do this?

I've tried making an object and tried using `.getWidth` and `.getHeight` but can't get it to work. I need specific code here because I've tried a lot of things but can't get it to work. Am I declaring width and height wrong in `DrawFrame`? Am creating the object the wrong way in `DrawCircle`?

Also, the variables i use in `DrawCircle`, should I have them in the constructor or not?

Comment: You´ve tried making an object of what class?

Answer (score 51):

You could make the variables public fields:

```
  public int width;
  public int height;

  DrawFrame() {
    this.width = 400;
    this.height = 400;
  }
```

You could then access the variables like so:

```
DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
int theWidth = frame.width;
int theHeight = frame.height;
```

A better solution, however, would be to make the variables private fields add two accessor methods to your class, keeping the data in the DrawFrame class encapsulated:

```
 private int width;
 private int height;

 DrawFrame() {
    this.width = 400;
    this.height = 400;
 }

  public int getWidth() {
     return this.width;
  }

  public int getHeight() {
     return this.height;
  }
```

Then you can get the width/height like so:

```
  DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
  int theWidth = frame.getWidth();
  int theHeight = frame.getHeight();
```

I strongly suggest you use the latter method.

Comment: i second the strong suggestion on the latter method (as do many others, i presume.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393001/do-any-other-developers-get-yelled-at-for-making-every-thing-public-closed)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help. I tried something like this earlier. I followed your code and still can't get it to work. There must be a problem somewhere else. Do you have any suggestions. The code in the OP works. My Main class looks like this:

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CircMain 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  JFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
  frame.show();
 }

}

Is this what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In order to modify variables from different classes, I made them extend the class they were to modify. I also made the super class's variables static so they can be changed by anything that inherits them. I also made them protected for more flexibility.

**Source:** Bad experiences. Good lessons.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried making an object and tried
>   using .getWidth and .getHeight but
>   can't get it to work.

That´s because you are not setting the width and height fields in JFrame, but you are setting them on local variables. Fields HEIGHT and WIDTH are inhereted from ImageObserver

```
Fields inherited from interface java.awt.image.ImageObserver
ABORT, ALLBITS, ERROR, FRAMEBITS, HEIGHT, PROPERTIES, SOMEBITS, WIDTH
```

See
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

If width and height represent state of the frame, then you could refactorize them to fields, and write getters for them.

Then, you could create a Constructor that receives both values as parameters

```
public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {
 private int width;
 private int height;

 DrawFrame(int _width, int _height){

   this.width = _width;
   this.height = _height;

   //other stuff here
}
 public int getWidth(){}
 public int getHeight(){}

 //other methods
}
```

If widht and height are going to be constant (after created) then you should use the **final** modifier. This way, once they are assigned a value, they can´t be modified.

> Also, the variables i use in
>   DrawCircle, should I have them in the
>   constructor or not?

The way it is writen now, will only allow you to create **one type of circle**. If you wan´t to create different circles, you should overload the constructor with one with arguments).

For example, if you want to change the attributes xPoint and yPoint, you could have a constructor

```
public DrawCircle(int _xpoint, int _ypoint){
  //build circle here.
 }
```

EDIT:

```
Where does _width and _height come from?
```

Those are arguments to constructors. You set values on them when you call the Constructor method.

> In DrawFrame I set width and height.
>   In DrawCircle I need to access the
>   width and height of DrawFrame. How do
>   I do this?

```
DrawFrame(){
   int width = 400;
   int height =400;

   /*
   * call DrawCircle constructor
   */
   content.pane(new DrawCircle(width,height));

   // other stuff

}
```

Now when the DrawCircle constructor executes, it will receive the values you used in DrawFrame  as _width and _height respectively.

EDIT:

Try doing

```
 DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();//constructor contains code on previous edit.
 frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
```

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: Thatnks for your help, and apologies for not getting it. I can't get it to work. Unfortunately I'm not better off that I was 5 hours ago. Where does _width and _height come from? I'm sort of getting bits of lots of different ways of doing, but no specific one way of doing it.

Comment: But what passes them into the constructor? I assumed from my main:

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new DrawFrame(400,400);
        frame.show();
    }

I tried this and it didn't work. Essentially I'm still where I was at 9am this morning. I suspect the stuff you are telling me doesn't work with the other code I have.

Thanks for your help, I'll leave learning java til another day.

Comment: ok. See my edit now. Maybe you should try something simpler. I dont think this is the way to learn either java or swing.

Comment: I'm totally confused. Too many bit-part answers. I'm too new to java to not get confused amongst all the suggestions. I spent 8 hours trying to pass/access a variable. Sometimes you just need to see the code to get it. I suspect I came close numerous times. 

Thanks for your help but you totally confused me.

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is the width and height of the frame in the circle, why not pass the DrawFrame width and height into the DrawCircle constructor:

```
public DrawCircle(int w, int h){
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    diBig = 300;
    diSmall = 10;
    maxRad = (diBig/2) - diSmall;
    xSq = 50;
    ySq = 50;
    xPoint = 200;
    yPoint = 200;
}
```

you could also add a couple new methods to DrawCircle:

```
public void setWidth(int w) 
   this.w = w;

public void setHeight(int h)
   this.h = h;
```

or even:

```
public void setDimension(Dimension d) {
   w=d.width;
   h=d.height;
}
```

if you go down this route, you will need to update DrawFrame to make a local var of the DrawCircle on which to call these methods.

**edit:**

when changing the DrawCircle constructor as described at the top of my post, dont forget to add the width and height to the call to the constructor in DrawFrame:

```
public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {
 public DrawFrame() {
    int width = 400;
    int height = 400;

    setTitle("Frame");
    setSize(width, height);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                    System.exit(0);
            }
    });

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    //pass in the width and height to the DrawCircle contstructor
    contentPane.add(new DrawCircle(width, height));
 }
}
```

Comment: I get errors saying "the constructor DrawCircle is undefined"

Comment: johnrambo, your compiler was probably complaining because you changed the params to the constructor but you didnt change the call in DrawFrame which was still referencing the no-arg constructor.  see my edit, please.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding the problem correctly, but it looks like you don't have a reference back to your DrawFrame object from DrawCircle.

Try this:

Change your constructor signature for DrawCircle to take in a DrawFrame object.  Within the constructor, set the class variable "d" to the DrawFrame object you just took in.  Now add the getWidth/getHeight methods to DrawFrame as mentioned in previous answers.  See if that allows you to get what you're looking for.

Your DrawCircle constructor should be changed to something like:

```
public DrawCircle(DrawFrame frame)
{
    d = frame;
    w = 400;
    h = 400;
    diBig = 300;
    diSmall = 10;
    maxRad = (diBig/2) - diSmall;
    xSq = 50;
    ySq = 50;
    xPoint = 200;
    yPoint = 200;
}
```

The last line of code in DrawFrame should look something like:

```
contentPane.add(new DrawCircle(this));
```

Then, try using d.getheight(), d.getWidth() and so on within DrawCircle.  This assumes you still have those methods available on DrawFrame to access them, of course.

Comment: Hi, tried it. Can't get it to work. I've tried so many diofferent things it's possible the error is from somewhere else. I think you understand my problem, but just let me clarify:

I set the width and height in DrawFrame
In DrawCircle I need to be able to access the values of width and height. In my code above (which works) I'm resetting manually in the constructor rather than getting it from DrawFrame. I need to be able to set the width and height once only.

Comment: I see, I copied your constructor for DrawCircle exactly and just added the parameter and the first line. In light of your comment, it seems like it would also be necessary to add: "w = d.getWidth(); h = d.getHeight();" in place of "w = 400; h = 400;"

Answer (score 0):

Filename=url.java

```
public class url {

    public static final String BASEURL = "http://192.168.1.122/";

}
```

if u want to call the variable just use this:

**url.BASEURL** + "your code here";

Answer (score 0):

Java inbuilt libraries support only AIFC, AIFF, AU, SND and WAVE formats.
Here I only discussed playing an audio file using Clip only and see the various methods of a clip.

1. Create a main class `PlayAudio.java`.
2. Create helper class `Audio.java`.

**PlayAudio.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
public class PlayAudio {
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, 
LineUnavailableException {

    PlayMp3 playMp3;
    playMp3=new PlayMp3();


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Choice :-");
        System.out.println("1. Play");
        System.out.println("2. pause");
        System.out.println("3. resume");
        System.out.println("4. restart");
        System.out.println("5. stop");

        System.out.println(PlayMp3.status);
        System.out.println(":::- ");
        int c = sc.nextInt();

        if (c ==5){

            playMp3.stop();
            break;
        }

        switch (c) {
            case 1:
                playMp3.play();
                break;
            case 2:
                playMp3.pause();
                break;
            case 3:
                playMp3.resume();
                break;
            case 4:
                playMp3.restart();
                break;
            case 5:
                playMp3.stop();
            default:
                System.out.println("Please Enter Valid Option :-");

        }
    }
    sc.close();
   }
}
```

**Audio.java**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Audio {

private String filePath="mp.snd";
public static String status="paused";
private Long currentFrame=0L;
private Clip clip;

private AudioInputStream audioInputStream;

public Audio() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath));

    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

    clip.open(audioInputStream);

}


public void play(){
    clip.start();
    status = "playing";
}

public void pause(){

    if (status.equals("paused")) {
        System.out.println("audio is already paused");
        return;
    }
    currentFrame = clip.getMicrosecondPosition();
    clip.stop();
    status = "paused";
}
public void resume() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    if (status.equals("play"))
    {
        System.out.println("Audio is already being playing");
        return;
    }
    clip.close();

    //starts again and goes to currentFrame
    resetAudioStream();
    clip.setMicrosecondPosition(currentFrame);
    play();
    status="playing";

}

public void restart() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    clip.stop();
    clip.close();
    resetAudioStream();
    currentFrame = 0L;
    clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
    play();
    status="Playing from start";
}

public void stop(){

    currentFrame = 0L;
    clip.stop();
    clip.close();
    status="stopped";
}

private void resetAudioStream() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {

    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath).getAbsoluteFile());
    clip.open(audioInputStream);

   }

}
```