# Java - Encapsulate fields into different file... (with IDE)

Tags: java, ide, encapsulation

I would like to encapsulate my fields (variables), into a different file. Like getting out the logic of my application into a different file (logic.java ?), where every class could access the variables that should be "global".

Netbeans is capable of doing encapsulation, but it will just put a list of setter/getter functions into the same file.

(Later, I would like to call the functions with `Logic lo = new Logic();`, and `lo.getValue()`, for example.)

If there is a better way of doing this, please enlighten me, and I'll delete the question. (The classes are in different package. **app.logic**; **app.desk**; **app.net**, etc.)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Let's say, you write a Class, with variables. Which should be available globally. (Let's say you make a game, where you should keep track of the difficulty, etc.) You want to modify those vaalues, in two Classes later. But you can't do that, unless the two classes have the same parent (extends), or the variables are global and the package is the same. || Tl;dr: I want to have a set of variables, and modify, read them accross my application.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class | Peter's answer is the same, making the variables accessible through accessors. I want to do the same. But I don't really want to do all the work by myself.

Comment: You want a global singleton object? Why cant you just select the variables/nerissa you want and do a "move" refactor?

Comment: Where can I find the "move" refactor option in Netbeans?

Comment: I don't understand if you are looking for an IDEA, an automation tool, a programming solution, or what?

Comment: Automation tool. Which would move the accessors into a different file, which I could use later, to access and/or modify the variables.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here are advanced refactoring capabilities, and for that I'd suggest you take a look at IntelliJ IDEA (The community edition is free to use and download and is available for all platforms).

Take a look at it [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly but what you can do is implement a singleton class:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }

    // members, getters and setters
}
```

Now this guarantees that you only have one instance of `Singleton` in your entire application that can be obtained anywhere with `Singleton.getInstance()`.

Comment: Yepp, I want to do this. But with a tool, not by hand.