# Why are the 'x' and 'y' variables of the Java AWT 'Point' class publicly accessible?

Tags: java, scope, precision, point

I'm doing some processing of images and in my work I use the package `java.awt.geom`. I am use the class [`Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html). This class extends from `Point2D` and inherits get methods that return double. `Point` is meant to be an integer representation of a point.

To access the integer `x` and `y` values in `Point` you need to use publicly accessible variable `x` and `y`; My question is

1) Isn't it bad practice to allow public access to an instance variable? eg. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class)

2) Is there a better design of this?

Comment: Do you really mean `class variable`? Make note that they are different from instance variables.

Comment: Yes, I modified the question, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is bad practice (at least by today's standards), but there are a few reasons for this...

1. The super-class `Point2D` needs to be as generic as possible
2. Backwards-compatibility
3. Convenience

In detail...

1. The super-class `Point2D` is a generic object used to represent any kind of point that can be represented in a 2D space. In order to have maximum use as a generic class, the point needs to allow for the highest level of precision possible (ie a `double`). This is evident by the `getX()` and `getY()` methods that return `double`s. By using `double`s, it allows any sub-class to be compatible with these methods, as a double is the largest primitive java number type with precision, so any sub-class that uses any other primitive numerical variable will always be able to return it as a `double` without losing any precision. 
   You can therefore think of `Point` as being a simplified version of `Point2D`, that doesn't maintain any precision - however it must still conform to the abstract method declarations of the super-class `Point2D`. An `int` can be cast into a `double` directly by the JVM without losing any precision - if `Point2D` were something other than a `double`, you would lose some of the precision during the cast. (For example, you couldn't cast it to a `float`, as larger `int` values wouldn't be able to be directly represented as a `float` without chopping off some of the higher numbers)
2. The Point class was introduced in Java 1.0. To maintain backwards compatibility, access to these variables needs to be maintained, even though it may not be best practice. You'll notice this in other early classes, such as the variable `File.separator`
3. `Point` is a class that is used in a lot of places, and itself is still a pretty generic object. It is much easier/simpler/quicker for programmers to reference an `int` directly then it is to cast every time you want to get the value `(int)getX()`. It is also quicker to process by the JVM, as it doesn't need to convert an `int` to a `double`, and then back to an `int` again.

If you want a better design, you would probably be best to create additional methods for accessing the `int` values as `int`s - ie create the methods `getXInt()` and `getYInt()`, and then change the variables back to being non-public (provided you don't need to retain backwards compatibility).

Comment: Yup.  Short answer: it's considered a mistake that we have to live with now for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes it is bad practise. The Point was introduced in JDK 1.0, Java always tries to keep backward compatibility that's why this weren't changed in the past I think.

There are getters for `x` and `y`. They are returning a double because of the abstract method declaration in `Point2D`. This isn't nice but can safely casted to an `int` as the value of the Point is returned which actually is an `int`.

2) If you need to deal with AWT you should simply accept this.