# Accessing class A from class B

Tags: java

I am doing this piece of school work. its about bin packing problem but its a bit modified about a trolley. There can be two or more piles inside the trolley. What I have done so far is made a parcel class and pile class. There are few rules to this that i need to follow. One of them is that when i put parcel (width 3) inside pile i cant put parcel (width 4) on top of it.

Yes i will have trolley class, pile class and parcel class.

What i am trying to do here make a function inside the pile class that changes the Width of the pile to whatever the width of the Parcel is that was just put in. How do I access parcel width from pile class ? will it just be getW() ? much appreciated the help. Or should i do this inside the trolley class ? not exactly sure how to implement this.

```
public class Parcel {
private int H;
private int W;
private int customer;

Parcel(int inH, int inW, int inCustomer){
    this.H = inH;
    this.W = inW;
    this.customer = inCustomer;
}

public int setH(){

    int x = (int )(Math.random() * 50 + 1);

    return x;
}

public int setW(){

    int y = (int )(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

    return y;
}

public int getW(){
    return W;
}

public int getH(){
    return H;
}
```

Comment: `(expressionThatReducesToAParcel).getW()` should work just fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setW()` is misnamed. It should be `randomizeWidth()`. What you should consider doing is to give the above class a valid width setter method, `setWidth(int width)` that set's the W variable (rename it to `width` to comply with Java naming conventions -- variable names should begin with a lower-case letter) so that outside classes can call the method and set the width.

Pile should likewise have valid setters and getters for its width and other properties. Pile can then call the Parcel methods above and use the information to set its width. If Pile object holds Parcel objects, then it's probably better for Pile to set its own width based on the widths of the Parcel objects it holds. So my suggestion is that Parcel ***not*** set a Pile's width.

Comment: Maybe `randomize` instead of `setRandom`.  Or `makeUnitTestingUnnecessarilyHard`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: LOL, great idea -- so implemented!

Comment: thanks, but i don't want the other classes to change anything in this class. I want my other class (pile class) to set the width of pile to be width of parcel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that pile has a field of type parcel, you can just call the getter.

```
public class Pile
{

    Parcel parcel;
    public Pile()
    {
        //instanciate parcel here;
    }


    public void someMethod
    {
        int w = this.parcel.getW();
    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels intended that to be a `w`