# Get value from Map field of List element

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I want to draw a String value from `otherclass2`. How can I do this?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<otherclass> list = new ArrayList<otherclass>();

        list.add(new otherclass());
    }
}


public class otherclass {
    private Map<String, otherclass2> maps = new HashMap<String, otherclass2>();
}

public class otherclass2 {
    String value = "I want this String";
}
```

Should I use `list.get()`? Or is there another approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing a variable from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class)

Comment: First you need to add some entries to the `maps` field of your `otherclass` instance (note: please use UpperCase as in OtherClass for class names). One way to do this is to call [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) in the constructor of `otherclass` with some `String` and `new otherclass2()`. You will need some way of accessing `maps` from `Main`, possibly through a public `get` method in `otherclass` which uses the same method of `maps`. Then just retrieve the `otherclass2` instance from `maps` using a key and print its `value` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the value of `otherclass2` because your list contain instance of `otherclass` and the `otherclass` is have a `private maps` => so that from the `list.get(0)` you can not access the `maps` => can not access `maps` also mean you can not access `otherclass2` value.

Second problem is that you have not init `otherclass2` and put it into `maps`.

To solve you problem (you should create get/setter instead of use public like here):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<otherclass> list = new ArrayList<otherclass>();
        list.add(new otherclass());
        otherclass other = list.get(0);
        String your_value = other.maps.get("first").value;
        System.out.println(your_value);
    }
}

public class otherclass{
    public Map<String, otherclass2> maps = new HashMap<String, otherclass2>();
    public otherclass(){
        maps.put("first", new otherclass2());
    }
}

public class otherclass2{
    public String value = "I want this String"
}
```