# Using variable from another class

Tags: java, variables, processing

I'm sure this is quite simple but I've tried checking google and other peoples questions on this site but can't make sense of it. Thank you for your help in advance.

I'm making a simple game. I'm trying to set up a collision detection but can't get it to work. What I'm trying to do is set a boolean to detect whether a fishing boat (player1) is hit by a shark (if so then a life is lost).

For the shark class I set a variable called SHARK1 for the color of the shark. I then set a for loop for the fishing boat to check if the color of the shark is ever detected to collide with the boat. However, the color of the shark is defined in the Shark class and I was wondering how I could use that variable in the Fishing Boat class. Code below.

```
//shark class

    class Shark
{
  int x, y, dx, dy;
  int w=37;
  int h=50;
  public PImage sharkPic;

  public final color sharkColor;


  Shark(int x, int y, int dx, int dy)
  {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.dx=dx;
    this.dy=dy;
    sharkPic=loadImage("images/shark.png");
    sharkPic.resize(w,h);
    this.sharkColor=sharkPic.get(20,20);
  }
}

//fishing boat class

    class Fisherman
{
  int x;
  int y;
  Shark shark;

  Fisherman(int x, int y, Shark shark)
  {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.shark=shark;
  }

  void render()
  {
    fill(255,255,0);
    rect(x,y, 80,20, 7);
    rect(x+40,y-50, 10,50);
    fill(255,0,0);
    triangle(x+25,y-40, x+40,y-50, x+40,y-30);
  }

  boolean sharkHitBoat()
  {
    for (int i=y; i<(y+20); i++)
    {
      color detectedColour;
      detectedColour = get(i, y+20);
      if (detectedColour==shark.sharkColor) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

} //class
```

I would then use the boolean in the main class so the player would lose a life if collision is detected and when 3 lives are lost then game over. There might be an easier way to achieve this but I was wondering if this is possible the way I'm doing it (if not then advice would be greatly appreciated). If there is some other code you need to see to help let me know and I can provide

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, a website where you can get help on specific problems with code. Start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and what questions are [suitable for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones are [not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You might also want to check out [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing a variable from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class)

Comment: it might make more sense to pass all the Sharks to each boat and loop the list of sharks checking if they collide with your boat. currently you don't pass anything and it would not make much sense for a Shark to be part of your Fisherman class

Answer (score 1):

This is not how I would do collision detection. Instead, I would simply use bounding boxes around the shark and the boat and check whether those boxes overlap. You can read more about collision detection in Processing [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

But to answer your question, you can use variables in one class from another class either by passing the variable in, or by referencing an instance of the class.

First off, `SHARK1` is not a great variable name, so let's call it `sharkColor`. Then, we have to make sure that it's a class-level variable, defined at the top of the class:

```
class Shark
{
  color sharkColor;
  //rest of class
```

The code you wrote means that `SHARK1` will only be available inside the constructor, which is definitely not what you want.

Now that we have that, we could pass the value of the variable directly into both classes. Something like this:

```
color colorForShark = color(whatever);
Shark shark = new Shark(colorForShark);
Fisherman fisherman = new Fisherman(colorForShark);
```

Then each class would take the color into its constructor, store it in a class-level variable, and use it however it wanted. This is pretty straightforward, but it assumes that every shark has the same color.

Or we could pass the shark in directly to the `Fisherman`, like this:

```
Shark shark = new Shark();
Fisherman fisherman = new Fisherman(shark);
```

You could also pass in an `ArrayList` of `Shark` instances and loop over them.

Anyway, now the `Fisherman` class has a `Shark` variable, we can then get to the shark's color using the `.` dot operator:

```
shark.sharkColor
```

Comment: I feel like the Fisherman class shouldn't contain a Shark.. it doesn't make sense to me. I feel like a much better solution is to create a method that takes a Shark or list of Sharks and checks for collisions.

Comment: furthermore if OP wanted to say add whales or dolphins, they could easily do so if those class all extend say SeeAnimal and then for the Fisherman class have a method like hitBoat(SeeAnimal) or something

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I don't necessarily disagree with you, but I think that advice is slightly outside the bounds of what I was trying to answer. Feel free to provide your own answer, but note that the OP isn't really asking about their design.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand as my coding level is still quite basic. I have moved the variable to the top of the Shark class (public final color sharkColor;) but this variable is still not recognised by the Fisherman class. Also the sharkColor variable is defined in the Shark constructor as (this.sharkColor=sharkPic.get(20,20);) - I have made sharkPic a public variable at the top of the class but that is not recognised by the Fisherman class either.

Comment: @codenoob You need to pass either the color or the shark itself into the `Fisherman` constructor, then save it to a class-level variable in order to use it.

Answer (score -1):

There is two issues here.

The first issue I see is with the scope of the variable SHARK1. You are creating this variable in the Shark constructor and therefor the scope is only within the Shark constructor meaning the variable is not visible outside of the constructor. Have a read of this article for more information on variable scope : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Change the Shark class to the below. Notice I have added a class level variable for the Shark's colour.

```
class Shark
{
  int x, y, dx, dy;
  int w=37;
  int h=50;
  PImage sharkPic;
  public final Color sharkColor;

  Shark(int x, int y, int dx, int dy)
  {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.dx=dx;
    this.dy=dy;
    sharkPic=loadImage("images/shark.png");
    sharkPic.resize(w,h);
    this.sharkColor= sharkPic.get(20,20); //variable for shark color thats needed for collision detection
  }
```

The second issue is that your Fisherman class doesn't know anything about your Shark class. You will need to pass an instance of Shark into the Fisherman class. See below:

```
class Fisherman {
        int x;
        int y;
        Shark shark;

        Fisherman(int x, int y, Shark shark) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.shark = shark;
        }

        void render() {
            fill(255, 255, 0);
            rect(x, y, 80, 20, 7);
            rect(x + 40, y - 50, 10, 50);
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            triangle(x + 25, y - 40, x + 40, y - 50, x + 40, y - 30);
        }

        boolean sharkHitBoat() {
            for (int i = y; i < (y + 20); i++) {
                Color detectedColour = get(i, y + 20);
                if (detectedColour == shark.sharkColor) //this is where I'm putting the color variable, this causes an error at the moment.
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now you can do the following:

```
 Shark shark = new Shark(1, 2, 3, 4);
 Fisherman fisherman = new Fisherman(1, 2, shark);
 fisherman.sharkHitBoat();
```

Comment: I have added the public final color line under the shark class rather than the constructor like you have advised but the boolean in the Fisherman class still does not recognise the color variable

Comment: Can you add the error here so that I can help some more.

Comment: Sure, the line of code is "if (detectedColour==sharkColor)" and the error is variable sharkColor does not exist. (I changed the name of the variable from SHARK1 to sharkColor and changed all instances of the name SHARK1 to sharkColor)

Comment: @codenoob .. Sorry the confusion here. The reason you are getting this error is because your Fisherman class doesn't know anything about your Shark class. I've updated my answer above to show a better working example

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: Nothing comes up under errors but it highlights the same line as before - if (detectedColour==shark.sharkColor)

Comment: I'm assuming it means that the program cannot use this.sharkColor= sharkPic.get(20,20); to resolve the color of the shark?

Comment: Can you add the error to your original post. Maybe a screenshot of your editor would help.