# How to use variables declared in another class?

Tags: java

If I have declared an `int` variable called `impart` and declared it in `class A`, and then I want to call it in `class B` and display it there. How would I go about doing that? I have heard you can do it by using the reserved keyword 'import', can somebody show me that way?

Comment: `import` is a reserved word in Java and cannot be used as a variable name.

Comment: Is this a member of the class?

Comment: For additional help, please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]

Comment: @Blobonat Please help us teach accepted OO concepts and patterns. `public` variables are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing a variable from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the variable Public such as 
`public int potato = 15;` Than that can be called in any class.
Or if you want your code to be better declare a private variable then create a method to return said variable.

```
public class a
{
      b wow = new b();

      wow.getPotato();
}

public class b
{

private potato;

public b()
{
//You dont neccessarily need this as there is a default constructor
}
public int getPotato()

return potato;

}
```

Comment: This is of course the standard way, but you can also access directly the variable if it is declared as `public` or you can also declare it as `static` depending from the context and avoid the instantiation of an object (it's not specified in the question).

Comment: I did mention that you can declare it as public variable.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to do something like this:

```
public class A {
  // you still have to set a value for i
  private int i;

  public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    // now you can use the value with
    a.getI();
  }
}
```

you could also set the variable public and access it directly (or make A static as well as the variable, then you can access it without instantiating A) but this is bad coding practice

Answer (score 0):

You create a Object of that Class and then call the getter method for the variable.

```
A aclass = new A();

aclass.getImport();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the variable static, you can use `int b = A.impart;`. Making the variable static allows you to cross it over to another class without having to get a reference to the class.