# Java: Accessing different variables in a different class to be used within a conditional statement

Tags: java, getter-setter, bluej

I have done some research on the forums and found this to be most applicable my question but the solution doesn't work: [accessing a variable from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class)

So I am trying to access two variables in my "LibraryCard" class:

```
    private int limit;
    private int booksBorrowed;
```

I found that if I want to access them in my second class "Student" I have to add a get method in my "LibraryCard" class:

```
    public int getlimit()
    {
    return this.limit;
    }

    public int getbooksBorrowed()
    {
    return this.booksBorrowed;
    }
```

After accessing these 2 variables I need to use them in an if statement in my "Student" class:
Which i have implemented this way

```
    public boolean finishedStudies()
    {
    if ( (this.booksBorrowed = 0) && (this.booksBorrowed >= this.limit)) {
        return true;
    }

    else
       return false;
    }
```

When i try to compile it BlueJ says it cannot find variable booksBorrowed and limit

I am very new to Java and Programming in general, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `this` means?

Comment: ` if ( (this.booksBorrowed = 0) && (this.booksBorrowed >= this.limit)) {` There are multiple errors here, in addition to the problem of using "this" instead of methods of an instance of LibraryCard. The logic (usage of `=` and `&&`) does not make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the create an instance of your LibraryCard class inside your Student class and then you can access the two variables by invoking the getters on that instance:

```
LibraryCard card = new LibraryCard();
int limit = card.getlimit();
int booksBorrowed = card.getbooksBorrowed();
```

Comment: I have a few follow up questions I hope you don't mind answering:
1. In what section does this code go into? In BlueJ it's split up between variables, constructors and methods
2. what does "card." do exactly in this specific context

Comment: I can't really answer any of those questions since I do not know what you are trying to do. You should watch some tutorials on Object Oriented Programming in Java