# How to access to a variable from class to class in java

Tags: java, class

Nokta class is coordinates of x and y and Cizgi class is the line between two points. I am trying to access x and y from Cizgi class and calculate the distance between those two points. I am trying to access but i couldn't. How can i access x and y from Cizgi class?

```
public class Cizgi {

    Nokta n1;
    Nokta n2;
    public Cizgi(Nokta nokta1, Nokta nokta2) {
        n1 = nokta1;
        n2 = nokta2;
    }
}

public class Nokta {
     int x;
     int y;

        Nokta(int x, int y){
            this.x= x;
            this.y=y;
        }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nokta nokta1= new Nokta(3,5);
        Nokta nokta2= new Nokta(6,1);
        Cizgi cizgi1=new Cizgi(nokta1, nokta2);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing a variable from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022880/accessing-a-variable-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not configured "visibility access" like private/protected/public it will public in package access and private in out of package.

so:

```java
public class Cizgi {     
    private Nokta n1;
    private Nokta n2;

    public Cizgi(Nokta nokta1, Nokta nokta2) {
        n1 = nokta1;
        n2 = nokta2;
    }

    public Nokta getNokta1() {
        return this.n1;
    }

    public Nokta getNokta2() {
        return this.n2;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Nokta {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    Nokta(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nokta nokta1 = new Nokta(3, 5);
        Nokta nokta2 = new Nokta(6, 1);
        Cizgi cizgi1 = new Cizgi(nokta1, nokta2);   

        // you can access
        int nokta2x1 = cizgi1.getNokta2().getX()
    }
}
```

**Update for comment.**

```java
public class Cizgi {     
    Nokta n1;
    Nokta n2;

    public Cizgi(Nokta nokta1, Nokta nokta2) {
        n1 = nokta1;
        n2 = nokta2;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Nokta {
    int x;
    int y;
    static int z;

    Nokta(int x, int y) {
        z = x; (here not work "this". Work: "Nokta.z")
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nokta nokta1 = new Nokta(3, 5);
        Nokta nokta2 = new Nokta(6, 1);
 
        Cizgi cizgi1 = new Cizgi(nokta1, nokta2);  
        Cizgi cizgi2 = new Cizgi(nokta2, nokta1);  

        // you can access
        int x1 = cizgi1.n1.x; // 3
        int staticX1 = Nokta.z; // 3

        int x2 = cizgi2.n1.x; // 6
        int staticX2 = Nokta.z; // 6 (change: 3 -> 6)
        // error: int z = cizgi2.n1.z;
    }
}
```

Comment: side note: You can use Lombok projekt for getter/setter shortcut.
https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: Can i access x and y at Cizgi class with the same way without cizgi.1 ?

Comment: If not configurated access level, and all 3 classes in one package, when example access chain: "int x = cizgi1.n1.x". Because Cizgi is containing Nkta instances and Nokta instance is containing int values.

Comment: You need "cizgi1" because this is one instance. Not "static". If I understand what you would like.

Comment: Check: "Update for comment." block in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create getters?

```java
public Nokta getNokta1() {
    return nokta1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inheritance here. Make a separate class you have made 3 public classes, which will show a compile-time error.If you don't know about inheritance, go learn about it there are many tutorials about it on youtube, also you can also use interfaces here.

```
    public class Cizgi {

    Nokta n1;
    Nokta n2;
    public Cizgi(Nokta nokta1, Nokta nokta2) {
        n1 = nokta1;
        n2 = nokta2;
    }
}
```

make another class, a new class.

```
 public class Nokta extends Cizgi{
     int x;
     int y;

        Nokta(int x, int y){
            this.x= x;
            this.y=y;
        }
}
```

now another class, your main class

```
    public class Main extends Nokta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nokta nokta1= new Nokta(3,5);
        Nokta nokta2= new Nokta(6,1);
        Cizgi cizgi1=new Cizgi(nokta1, nokta2);      
    }
}
```